# Xcode 4 Organizer on Mac, How to Run without Xcode?

Tags: iphone, organizer

Is there a way to run the Organizer without XCODE to add a device to a Porthole?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Probably not since it's built into XCode and is not listed in the Developer Tools menu.

But you can open organizer without opening an entire XCode project.  Just open XCode and click  SHIFT + CMD + 2 or Window > Organizer.

*OR* you can go to developer.apple.com > Provisioning Portal > Devices and add a device manually